# PWA add to home screen does not work as expected

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I've started with PWA, I want to add home screen icon to my app, but it's added to apps menu instead of home screen

Answer (score 0):

It's usually added to BOTH app and home screen.
But many times it will place the icon on the second home screen for me.
Even if there is a spot open on the first.