# PWA - Chrome Add-To-Home-screen adds as WebAPK but not to home screen

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I have a Progressive Web App that meets all the Google Chrome criteria for installation and passes the Audit tests.  Using Chrome, when I surf to the PWA's URL and select "Add To Home screen" (either from the menu or from the popup) it will install as an app via WebAPK - as expected.  The correct icon shows in the app list.  However, the app icon is not added to the Home screen - it is not on any of the home screens.

Shouldn't it also be added to the home screen as that is the expectation of "Add to Home screen"?

This SO thread suggests adding to both is the usual functionality.  But that is not happening for me.  [PWA add to home screen does not work as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55648039/pwa-add-to-home-screen-does-not-work-as-expected)

If it should also be added to the home screen, any suggestions as to what I may be doing wrong or where to investigate?

If it doesn't also add to home screen - shouldn't it?  Or change the menu item to "Install App" - so the user expectation is set correctly?

**EDIT 2021-09-18:**
It's been 2 years since this post and I've been distracted with other things (as many have the last 18 months).  But coming back to this project, I still have this issue.  Thanks to CherryDT for suggesting to update this post instead of creating a new one.

I created a minimal PWA (called PWATest) that successfully registers a service worker and shows the browser prompt to install the PWA. The browser prompt in Android Chrome (now Version 91.0.4472.124) shows at the bottom of the mobile screen and says "Add PWATest to Home screen". When I tap that prompt, the "Install app" dialog shows and I select "Install". I see "Adding PWATest...". After it is installed, the app icon is in the applications area with all the other app icons but there is no PWATest icon on the home screen (any of them).

I have cleared the cache and asked a friend to try with no difference.

I just went to bmw.com and installed their pwa.  Same thing.  The app icon showed only with the other application icons - no icon on the home screen.

I tried my pwa using Samsung Internet and again same result.

Comment: Android? - On mine, it usually adds to the second home screen.

Comment: Yep, Android.  Chrome 76. As mentioned it adds the icon to the apps, but not on any home screen.  if my PWA does not have a service worker (so chrome just adds a shortcut to home screen not the WebAPK install) it will add the icon to the last icon slot to the right (rightmost screen last icon slot).

Comment: If you have not done so, perhaps have someone who has not visited your HTTPS site give it a try. Just to rule out that it's not something goofy/cached on your device.

Comment: @Mathias - Good suggestion, I will do that and report back.

Comment: Different phones and user configurations may override the add to home screen default.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem recently: my PWA was installed in the applications but not on the screen.
However it worked a few weeks ago. I then assumed that I had changed a setting on my Android phone.

Bingo! In the home screen settings there is a check mark "add to home screen for new applications" which was unchecked.

(long press on the home screen to access the settings.)